# java code to create aws client using ec2 role or default credentials chain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, ec2-ami, aws-java-sdk-2.x

Below code creates AWS Credentials where access and secret keys are explicitly supplied.

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
  "<AWS accesskey>", 
  "<AWS secretkey>"
);
```

But the issue with this approach is in production I can not use it.
So what will be an equivalent java code that will obtain credential automatically from the aws credentials chain and create a credential object or some EC2 client.

Answer (score 2):

There are several alternatives you can use to store and recover your credentials in production. You should check the official documentation by AWS about '[Using the Default Credential Provider Chain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html)'. Basically, you can use any of these alternatives:

- Environment variables.
- Java system properties.
- The default credential profiles file.
- Amazon ECS container credentials.
- Instance profile credentials.

Depending on which one you choose it would use a different code. You have guidelines on how to use them in the above link.